# What is the best way to match a set of regular expressions in HashSet to a string in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, performance

I was wondering if I'm doing the following ASP.NET C# regexp match in the most efficient way?

I have a set of regular expressions in a HashSet that I need to match to an input string, so I do:

```
HashSet<string> hashMatchTo = new HashSet<string>();
hashMatchTo.Add(@"regexp 1");
hashMatchTo.Add(@"regexp 2");
hashMatchTo.Add(@"regexp 3");
hashMatchTo.Add(@"regexp 4");
hashMatchTo.Add(@"regexp 5");
//and so on

string strInputString = "Some string";

bool bMatched = false;
foreach (string strRegExp in hashMatchTo)
{
    Regex rx = new Regex(strRegExp, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (rx.IsMatch(strInputString))
    {
        bMatched = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems like yours is the only answer. Do you want to expand it below and I'll mark it?

Comment: You're using a HashSet, but you're always iterating it. A HashSet is optimized for random lookups, but not for iteration. If you just want to iterate, use a List<Regex> instead.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I chose HashSet is to eliminate duplicate entries.

Comment: If you're iterating more often than adding expressions, you should just use List.Contains before adding a new expression. If you're changing the list more often than that you use it, you're fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any thing wrong. I will consider readability over efficiency as long as it is fast enough and meets the business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Two things jump out at me.  The first is that you can populate a collection at the same time you create it, like so:

```
  HashSet<string> hashMatchTo = new HashSet<string>()
  {
      @"^regexp 1$", 
      @"^regexp 2$",
      @"^regexp 3$",
      @"^[\w\s]+$",
      @"^regexp 5$"
      //and so on
  };
```

The second is that you should use the static version of `IsMatch()`, like so:

```
  string strInputString = "Some string";

  bool bMatched = false;
  foreach (string strRegExp in hashMatchTo)
  {
      if (Regex.IsMatch(strInputString,  strRegExp, 
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
      {
          bMatched = true;
          break;
      }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(bMatched);
}
```

The reason for doing this is that the static Regex methods automatically cache whatever Regex objects they create.  But be aware that the cache size is only 15 by default; if you think you'll be using more than that, you'll need to increase the value of [CacheSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize.aspx) property.

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice suggestion. I'm not sure that I understand what that cache is for?

Comment: It saves the system having to create a new Regex object for each regex every time the `foreach` loop is performed.  In a tight loop, that can have serious impact on performance.

Comment: So in my example -- code in my OP -- I need to set this CacheSize to hashMatchTo.count, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is a simple "does match any? true/false" then concatenate all of your regex into one big regex and just run that.

```
string strRegexp = string.Join("|", listOfRegex.ToArray());

bool bIsMatched = Regex.IsMatch(strInputString, strRegExp, RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine(bMatched);
```

- No "foreach" looping
- Better readability
- No need to mess with the static Regex caching
- While processing it will short circuit much like it does in the loop version with "break", but less method calls will be made which (should) improve performance.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks. My only concern though is the "correctness" of using OR operator in that case. Do I need some version of regexp parentheses for each regexp part I'm OR'ing?

Comment: @ahmd0 - no you shouldn't need any extra parentheses because your task is only to check if ANY of the regexp are true. So a union of all of them would still produce your IS ANY TRUE answer.

Comment: Side note: supposing you *did* decide to add parens you could easily do that with a `Select` statement: `string.Join("|", listOfRegex.Select(r => "(" + r + ")"))` I think `string.Join` allows any `IEnumerable` so the `ToArray` is not strictly needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your set content, I don't know how many is really many. But you may think about searching criteria based on case by case basis. Make your program know what and where to search instead of running through all of hash-set content to check for possible issues. 
I used to work with a simple regular expression to extract from 2000 provided urls information that is to be displayed in a listview but it degraded the whole program performance severely.